# Is there any way to get the plain text from signed data using private key?

Tags: java, security, ssl, private-key

The plain text is signed using `java.security.Signature`. Below is the code used to sign the plain text

```
    public String getSignature(String plainText) throws Exception
    {
        KeyStore keyStore = loadKeyStore(); // A local method to read the keystore file from file system.
        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
        
        Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATUREALGO);
        privateSignature.initSign(privateKey);
        privateSignature.update(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    
        byte[] signature = privateSignature.sign();
        
        return String.valueOf(signature);

        // KEY_ALIAS_IN_KEYSTORE, KEYSTORE_PASSWORD and SIGNATUREALGO are all constant Strings
    }
```

**Note 1:** I found online a way to verify the signature using the public key [Java Code Examples for java.security.Signature#verify()](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.security.Signature&method=verify). But this is not what I require.

**Note 2:** I also found a ways to encrypt and decrypt as mentioned here [RSA Signing and Encryption in Java](https://niels.nu/blog/2016/java-rsa.html). But the use case I have in hand is to get the original plain text from a signed data. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you checked how the signature changes when you increase the data? How big is the signature if you sign 1 byte, 2 bytes, 1000 bytes, 1 million bytes?

Comment: Dear @Salman, you've very consistently written "singed" instead of "signed". "Singed" means "to scorch" (usually with fire), it's not related to cryptography.

Comment: what you want to achieve? are you aware that signing != encrypting? So signed text can still readable to anyone

Comment: Also: don't use `String.valueOf()` to turn the output of encryption methods to `String`, that won't work in many cases and if it works, it's due to random chance.

Comment: You already have plaintext and additionally a signature so where is the problem - just take the plaintext. Or was there something more that happened to the plaintext? Then you should show that code as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't retrieve the original content from just the signature.

The signature alone does not contain enough information to restore the original clear text, no matter what keys you have access to.

The basic idea of a signature is to send it together with the clear text. That means the clear text will be visible, but the signature can be used to verify that the message was written (or at least signed) by who claims to have done so and has not been tampered with since then.

Signing something is different from encrypting it. The two often uses the same or related technologies and both fall under cryptography.

Comment: There's an exception to this: so-called opaque S/MIME signatures (S/MIME Cryptographic Signed Data) encode the cleartext in the signature. Therefore it is possible (even necessary) to extract the signed cleartext from the such signatures.

Comment: @not2savvy: Personally I'd just describe that as "a signed message", because the signature (cryptographically speaking) is just a tiny part of that.

Comment: You are right: in the inside that’s the case, while from the outside it looks like one larger object.